# How to enable and disable listview items based on my quiz score?

Tags: android, android-listview

I have my List-view Item: Easy Medium Hard.
How am I going to Disable Medium and Hard? . and how to Enable it after
reaching certain score on "Easy" quiz . Please Help me guys. :(

This is my code.

```
    String classes[] = {"Easy", "Medium", "Hard" };


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, classes));

    }
    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        String easy = classes[position];
        try{
        Class openClass = Class.forName("first.project." + easy);
        Intent openIntent = new Intent(this , openClass);
        startActivity(openIntent);
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        finish();
    }
}
```

This is the code on my QuestionActivity

```
public class QuestionActivity extends Activity {
    // Called when the activity is first created. 

    EditText question = null;
    RadioButton answer1 = null;
    RadioButton answer2 = null;
    RadioButton answer3 = null;
    RadioButton answer4 = null;
    RadioGroup answers = null;
    Button finish = null;
    int selectedAnswer = -1;
    int quesIndex = 0;
    int numEvents = 0;
    int selected[] = null;
    int correctAns[] = null;
    boolean review =false;
    Button prev, next = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.question);

        TableLayout quizLayout = (TableLayout)  findViewById(R.id.quizLayout);
        quizLayout.setVisibility(android.view.View.INVISIBLE);

        try {
            question = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.question);
            answer1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.a0);
            answer2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.a1);
            answer3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.a2);
            answer4 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.a3);
            answers = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.answers);
            RadioGroup questionLayout = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.answers);
            Button finish = (Button)findViewById(R.id.finish);
            finish.setOnClickListener(finishListener);

            prev = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Prev);
            prev.setOnClickListener(prevListener);
            next = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Next);
            next.setOnClickListener(nextListener);


            selected = new int[Easy.getQuesList().length()];
            java.util.Arrays.fill(selected, -1);
            correctAns = new int[Easy.getQuesList().length()];
            java.util.Arrays.fill(correctAns, -1);


            this.showQuestion(0,review);

            quizLayout.setVisibility(android.view.View.VISIBLE);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("", e.getMessage().toString(), e.getCause());
                }

    }


    private void showQuestion(int qIndex,boolean review) {
        try {
            JSONObject aQues = Easy.getQuesList().getJSONObject(qIndex);
            String quesValue = aQues.getString("Question");
            if (correctAns[qIndex] == -1) {
                String correctAnsStr = aQues.getString("CorrectAnswer");
                correctAns[qIndex] = Integer.parseInt(correctAnsStr);
            }

            question.setText(quesValue.toCharArray(), 0, quesValue.length());
            answers.check(-1);
            answer1.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            answer2.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            answer3.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            answer4.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            JSONArray ansList = aQues.getJSONArray("Answers");
            String aAns = ansList.getJSONObject(0).getString("Answer");
            answer1.setText(aAns.toCharArray(), 0, aAns.length());
            aAns = ansList.getJSONObject(1).getString("Answer");
            answer2.setText(aAns.toCharArray(), 0, aAns.length());
            aAns = ansList.getJSONObject(2).getString("Answer");
            answer3.setText(aAns.toCharArray(), 0, aAns.length());
            aAns = ansList.getJSONObject(3).getString("Answer");
            answer4.setText(aAns.toCharArray(), 0, aAns.length());
            Log.d("",selected[qIndex]+"");
            if (selected[qIndex] == 0)
                answers.check(R.id.a0);
            if (selected[qIndex] == 1)
                answers.check(R.id.a1);
            if (selected[qIndex] == 2)
                answers.check(R.id.a2);
            if (selected[qIndex] == 3)
                answers.check(R.id.a3);

            setScoreTitle();
            if (quesIndex == (Easy.getQuesList().length()-1))
                next.setEnabled(false);

            if (quesIndex == 0)
                prev.setEnabled(false);

            if (quesIndex > 0)
                prev.setEnabled(true);

            if (quesIndex < (Easy.getQuesList().length()-1))
                next.setEnabled(true);


            if (review) {
                Log.d("review",selected[qIndex]+""+correctAns[qIndex]);;    
                if (selected[qIndex] != correctAns[qIndex]) {
                    if (selected[qIndex] == 0)
                        answer1.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                    if (selected[qIndex] == 1)
                        answer2.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                    if (selected[qIndex] == 2)
                        answer3.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                    if (selected[qIndex] == 3)
                        answer4.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                }
                if (correctAns[qIndex] == 0)
                    answer1.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                if (correctAns[qIndex] == 1)
                    answer2.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                if (correctAns[qIndex] == 2)
                    answer3.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                if (correctAns[qIndex] == 3)
                    answer4.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(this.getClass().toString(), e.getMessage(), e.getCause());
        }
    }


    private OnClickListener finishListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setAnswer();
            //Calculate Score
            int score = 0;
            for(int i=0; i<correctAns.length; i++){
                if ((correctAns[i] != -1) && (correctAns[i] == selected[i]))
                    score++;
            }
            AlertDialog alertDialog;
            alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(QuestionActivity.this).create();
            alertDialog.setTitle("Score");
            alertDialog.setMessage((score) +" out of " + (Easy.getQuesList().length()));

            alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "Retake", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    review = false;
                    quesIndex=0;
                    QuestionActivity.this.showQuestion(0, review);
                }
            });

            alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Review", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    review = true;
                    quesIndex=0;
                    QuestionActivity.this.showQuestion(0, review);
                }
            });

            alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE,"Quit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    review = false;
                    finish();
                }
            });

            alertDialog.show();

        }
    };

    private void setAnswer() {
        if (answer1.isChecked())
            selected[quesIndex] = 0;
        if (answer2.isChecked())
            selected[quesIndex] = 1;
        if (answer3.isChecked())
            selected[quesIndex] = 2;
        if (answer4.isChecked())
            selected[quesIndex] = 3;

        Log.d("",Arrays.toString(selected));
        Log.d("",Arrays.toString(correctAns));

    }

    private OnClickListener nextListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setAnswer();
            quesIndex++;
            if (quesIndex >= Easy.getQuesList().length())
                quesIndex = Easy.getQuesList().length() - 1;

            showQuestion(quesIndex,review);
        }
    };

        private OnClickListener prevListener = new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setAnswer();
                quesIndex--;
                if (quesIndex < 0)
                    quesIndex = 0;

                showQuestion(quesIndex,review);
                }
        };

        private void setScoreTitle() {
            this.setTitle("Question # " + (quesIndex+1)+ "/" + Easy.getQuesList().length());
        }


        @Override
         public void onBackPressed() {

                new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("Warning!!")
                .setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
                   {
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    finish();
                       }
                   })
                   .setNegativeButton("No", null)
                   .show();


               }
               }
```

Comment: Where is your score stored ?

Comment: I dont have Database for my score sir. I only show the score after the quiz. and thats it.

here's my code on my score.

int score = 0;
for(int i=0; i<correctAns.length; i++){
if ((correctAns[i] != -1) && (correctAns[i] == selected[i]))
score++;
}
AlertDialog alertDialog;
alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(QuestionActivity.this).create();
alertDialog.setTitle("Score");
alertDialog.setMessage((score) +" out of " + (Easy.getQuesList().length()));

Comment: Why are you making it complex using listview, while you can easily implement using buttons itself.

Comment: im thinking about it sir. but
 I still dont know the code on how to disable the other button.
and enable it after reaching the certain score on "easy".

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop like so:

```
int count = adapter.getCount();
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
 adapter.remove(adapter.getItem(i));
}
```

I think that should work

XcutionX

Comment: just change it to remove whichever one you need to.

Comment: how should I put it in my code ?.
when i Insert this code. 
it still not working :( .

Comment: Sorry didn't read the question properly. Look at the answer up ^^^ that should work. After finishing the quiz, check the score. If the score is whatever range it needs to be setEnabled(True) for medium and hard, but to begin with setEnabled(True) for just easy mode.

Answer (score 0):

this what i understood, what you are going to do is:

First of all the 'easy' button will be enabled and the rest of two will be disabled (I guess).

```
buttonEasy.setEnabled(true);
buttonMediun.setEnabled(false);
buttonHard.setEnabled(false);
```

then after the quiz with 'easy' level is finished, check the score if it has reached a certain value. If yes, then you will enable the 'Medium' button with the code:

`buttonMedium.setEnabled(true);`

Comment: if I switch to button..

yes exactly .. thats what I want to do on my Button.

Comment: but what should I do.I want to automatic enable the medium button after reaching a certain value of easy score.

Comment: @Spongkie What have you tried so far ? Show the whole activity code where you check the score.

Comment: I edited my question. I post the QuestionActivity Code
@shree202